# remove suffix from words of a string by condition

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to delete every 'abc' in a word of a sentence that is not **abc** and doesn't start with **abcxx** or **abcyy**.

so:

dog abc cat abcxx abcdfxx abcee abcyyli abcb

becomes to:

dog abc cat abcxx <strike>**abc**</strike>dfxx <strike>**abc**</strike>ee abcyyli <strike>**abc**</strike>b

It means:

dog abc cat abcxx dfxx ee abcyyli b

I was trying something like:

```js
var text = "dog abc cat abcxx abcdfxx abcee abcyyli abcb";
console.log(
  text.replace(/(^((?:abc(?!xx)(?!yy)).*)$)/g, '')
);
```

It knows to detect the problematic words if I run it on each word,
and delete all word (and not 'abc' only).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could simplify it with three lookaheads, two negative (no `xx`, no `yy`) and one positive (require `abc` followed by a character):

```js
const text = "dog abc cat abcxx abcdfxx abcee abcyyli abcb";
console.log(
  text.replace(/\babc(?!xx)(?!yy)(?=\w)/g, '')
)
```